# @ModelAttribute Spring MVC multiple select not setting the ArrayList

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, modelattribute

I am trying Spring MVC from basic tutorials. I have come to a problem where I am trying to bind data from HTML form to model object. There are few fields like

```
private String studentName;
private String studentHobby;
private Long studentMobile;
private Date studentDOB;
private ArrayList<String> studentSkills;
```

All fileds are setting properly and I can display them on another jsp properly except the Skills field which is ArrayList.

```
Name: ${student.studentName}<br>
Hobby: ${student.studentHobby}<br>
Mobile: ${student.studentMobile}<br>
DOB: ${student.studentDOB}<br>
Skills: ${student.studentSkills}<br>
```

My code is as follows:

```
package com.springMVC.controller;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.springMVC.model.Student;

@Controller
public class StudentAdmissionController 
{

@ModelAttribute
public void addCommonObjects(Model model)
{
    model.addAttribute("headerMsg","welcome to spring learning!");
}

@RequestMapping(value="/admissionForm",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getAdmissionForm() 
{
    System.out.println("inside getAdmission");
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("AdmissionForm");
    return model;
}




@RequestMapping(value="submitAdmissionForm",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView submitAdmissionForm(@ModelAttribute("student") Student student,BindingResult result)
{
    System.out.println("inside submitAdmissionForm name: "+student.getStudentName()+" hobby: "+student.getStudentHobby());

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("AdmissionSuccess");

    return model;
}
```

}

AdmissionForm.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<b>${headerMsg }</b>
    <form action="/SpringMVCDemo/submitAdmissionForm" method="post">
        studentName: <input type="text" name="studentName"><br>
        studentHobby: <input type="text" name="studentHobby"><br>
        studentMobile: <input type="text" name="studentMobile"><br>
        studentDOB: <input type="text" name="studentDOB"><br>
        StudenSkills: <select name="studentSkills" multiple>
                        <option value="java">java</option>
                        <option value="Java">java2</option>
                        <option value="JAVA">java3</option>
                      </select>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

AdmissionSuccess.jsp:

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>

     <%@ taglib uri='http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core' prefix='c'%>
     <%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>${headerMsg }</h1>
<h1>Congratulations!</h1>
<h2>Name: ${student.studentName}</h2><br>
<h2>Hobby: ${student.studentHobby}</h2><br>
<h2>Mobile: ${student.studentMobile}</h2><br>
<h2>${student.studentDOB}</h2><br>
<h2>Skills: ${student.studentSkills}</h2><br>
</body>
</html>
```

First of all this links bring the form http://localhost:8080/SpringMVCDemo/admissionForm.html

And after submitting same captured data is displayed in another jsp.

Comment: Post the code of Student. Change the type of studentiSkills to `List<String>`

Comment: @JBNizet you got me there! It was ArrayList<String>. I don't know why I wrote it like that. Thank you very much. Please add your comment as solution. Thank you very much...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `studentSkills` property must be of type `List<String>`, not `ArrayList<String>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %> 
<%@ taglib uri='http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core' prefix='c'%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>${headerMsg }</h1>
<h1>Congratulations!</h1>
<h2>Name: ${student.studentName}</h2><br>
<h2>Hobby: ${student.studentHobby}</h2><br>
<h2>Mobile: ${student.studentMobile}</h2><br>
<h2>Date of Birth: ${student.studentDOB}</h2><br>
<h2>Skills: ${student.studentSkills}</h2><br>
</body>
</html>
```